# Codeigniter 3.1.7 valid_email issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two sites using `Codeigniter`. Today I have updated sites to `Codeigniter 3.1.7` (from `3.1.6`). After that at one of this sites email validation had broken, `valid_email` validation rule doesn't work any more. On second site all fine. I had check out error logs and found error:

```
ERROR - 2018-02-06 10:13:21 --> Severity: Warning --> idn_to_ascii() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given /public_html/system/libraries/Form_validation.php 1235
```

Codeigniter's changlog says:

```
Updated Form Validation Library rule valid_email to use INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46 for non-ASCII domain names.
```

It seems to me that `INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46` constant is not defined. Site using `PHP Version 5.6.30`

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found discussion of this problem [here](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-69780-post-350527.html).

Issue is outdated ICU library (ICU version  4.2.1 was installed)

Answer (score 5):

Go to system/library/email.php and replace valid_email()

```
    public function valid_email($email)
    {
    if (function_exists('idn_to_ascii') && defined('INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46') && $atpos = strpos($email, '@'))
    {
        $email = self::substr($email, 0, ++$atpos).idn_to_ascii(self::substr($email, $atpos), 0, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46);
    }
    return (bool) filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

just get the latest library for email
Get the latest codeigniter zip file
then go to system->libraries->Email file
copy that email file and paste it into your previous Email.php library file then it will work

Comment: Both `Email.php` and `Form_validation.php` libraries need to be replaced with new ones. Thanks for this suggestion / worked great!

Comment: It’s natural that you always need to update to the latest version, but when the question was asked, 3.1.7 was the latest version

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a better way to sort out that issue.
As we all know that email library not supported in php 7.2 and that's why error occured

> idn_to_ascii(): INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 is deprecated

[Error Screenshot of codeigniter email library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjSFC.png)

**Quick Solution :**

- --> Go to cPanel 
  --> Select PHP version 
  --> change it to 7.1 instead of 7.2

Comment: Did you read the question? `PHP Version 5.6.30` was used on site.

Answer (score 0):

For my case. I am also facing this issue.

Error:

```
Severity: 8192 
Message: idn_to_ascii(): INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 is deprecated Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php 
Line Number: 1234
```

I downloaded the Latest CodeIgniter version. Then from the `system/libraries` folder copied `Email.php` and `Form_validation.php`. Then replaced with Existing Email.php and Form_validation.php at the same path.

After replace, It is start working Fine..!!

Thanks @Evgeny for Guide.

Comment: When this question was asked  Codeigniter 3.1.7 was the latest version.

Comment: There was Bug . Later it was fixed in the latest system library.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue would occur when you have incompatible CI and PHP version combinations. I mean newer PHP version and older CI version, vice-versa. I had PHP 7.3 on my machine and the CI repo/project I downloaded from github had CI version 3.1.5. I had to replace the system folder (of 3.1.5 with that of newer CI versions, 3.1.10 in my case) to resolve this issue